# How to get the a block's hash given its number to then feed to filter?

Tags: web3.py

I'm not sure if the first function is getting the hash for the block number given or something else.  But the second function doesn't want to accept the parameter.

```
last_block_hash = web3.eth.get_block(1000)["hash"].hex()
eventFilter = web3.eth.filter(
        "fromBlock" => last_block_hash,
        "topics" => [event_signature_hash]
    )

invalid argument 0: hex number with leading zero digits
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fromBlock` should be a block number, not a block hash, so it have to be like that:

```
eventFilter = web3.eth.filter(
        {"fromBlock": 1000,
        "topics": [event_signature_hash]}
    )
```

And you have a syntax error by mixing Python and JavaScript, Python use : not => to separate value

```
last_block_number = 1000
eventFilter = web3.eth.filter(
        {"fromBlock": last_block_number,
        "topics": [event_signature_hash]}
    )
```